# how to establish a VOIP call between two IP addresses Using Linphone core APIs

Tags: c++, c, voip

I dont have any experience on protocols side (like SIP/SDP/TCP/RTP), but i need help to make use of Linphone Lib or Linphone core APIs in Linux machines to make a VOIP call.

my requirement: I wanted to create custom application which can make a voip call using linphone core APIs to IP addresses (but not SIP address or SIP URI) of linux environments.

#1. what are the main configuration parameters required and to be set at linphone side.
#2. what are the APIs to be invoked to set the configuration parameters

I have seen some examples available in linphone-sdk/liblinphone/coreapi/help/examples/C/*
but those examples are using SIP uri as an input.

below are the APIs from Examples:

```
   linphone_core_new(); 
   Linphone_core_invite();
   linphone_core_accept_call();
   linphone_core_terminate_call();
```

etc,

I want to make use of Linphone core APIs or Linphone Library and make an outgoing call from one end(linux) then receive an incoming call from another End(Linux).

Actually I don't want to use Entire Linphone-sdk.

It will be very useful for me if someone can help on this.
Thanks in advance.

I tried to build linphone-sdk in Linux and then copied all .so files in to Custom directory.
I added .h files of linphone in custom directory as well.
Then I started compiling my code with .so files and .h files of Linphone.
Executed application after successful build but getting some below errors:

```
2022-11-17 07:25:56:210 liblinphone-error-Could not find a suitable soundcard with capabilities : 2
2022-11-17 07:25:56:210 liblinphone-error-Could not find a suitable soundcard with capabilities : 2
2022-11-17 07:25:56:210 liblinphone-error-Could not find a suitable soundcard with capabilities : 1
2022-11-17 07:25:56:210 liblinphone-error-Could not find a suitable soundcard with capabilities : 2
2022-11-17 07:25:56:212 bctbx-error-Error in connect: Cannot assign requested address
2022-11-17 07:25:56:212 bctbx-error-Error in connect: Cannot assign requested address
2022-11-17 07:25:56:212 liblinphone-warning-Lime X3DH support is not available
2022-11-17 07:25:59:536 bctbx-error-Error in connect: Cannot assign requested address
2022-11-17 07:25:59:536 liblinphone-error-Unable to determine IP version from signaling operation, no via header found
2022-11-17 07:25:59:537 mediastreamer-warning-Could not apply gain on sent RTP packets: gain control wasn't activated. Use audio_stream_enable_gain_control() before starting the stream.
2022-11-17 07:25:59:537 liblinphone-error-Unable to use audio device [0] as recording device
2022-11-17 07:25:59:537 liblinphone-error-Unable to use audio device [0] as playback device
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to config your sound card. Don't know your system, you can use PulseAudio or ALSA.
then, you can test the aplay -L and arecord -L

finnally, your linphone can point to a sound carm pcm or use the default, which is in the linphone config file (maybe .linphonerc)

if all of the above are done, now you can setup a sip call to another sip client. you can make two sip calls, and read the the first in and set it to the 2nd out, and read the 2nd in to the first out. then you get the two way voice.